# Regex: Match and Save filename in directory structure

Tags: regex, perl

Pattern: `((.*)\.html$)`

Input: docname.html

Result: Matches and $2 contains `docname`.

I always want `docname` in $2 whatever be the input. For example:

Pattern: `((.*)\.html$)`

Input: manual/docname.html

Result: Matches but $2 contains `manual/docname`.

What should be my pattern to always have `docname` in $2? Input may be like `docname.html`, `manual/docname.html`, `manual/docs/docname.html` etc.

Comment: Your regex will not match any of those sample inputs, because they all lack the `.html` extension.

Comment: Sorry, question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.` you can match everything except `/`,

```
$input =~ m|(([^/]*)\.html$)|;
```